# Duplicate mount-points for external disks after 22.04.1 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, external-hdd, symbolic-link, mountpoint

Just did an upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 with my external storage disks connected.

The system generated mount-points:

- 'Computer'/media/'homefolder'/4TB-WD-ElementsS - turned into
- 'Computer'/media/'homefolder'/4TB-WD-ElementsS**1**

breaking all my system/application references to `/media/'homefolder'/4TB-WD-ElementsS`.

Similar renaming occurred for all the other external drives.

Picture:

[image]

How do I switch back to "4TB-WD-ElementsS" and remove the new "4TB-WD-ElementsS**1**" duplicates?

**Added**: contents of /etc/fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=fa43ba46-1945-4acb-a0b2-c035ba801af5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=0D4A-32DB  /boot/efi       vfat    utf8            0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=3ebc7a53-18ad-45d7-a6ee-67633d0e8023 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=128161f0-2ec6-4dc6-9913-6e39189efb95 none            swap    sw              0       0
#UUID=0D4A-32DB /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
#UUID=5A0C-6CDC /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
UUID=5A0C-6CDC  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

"Disks" info on 4TB-WD-ElementsS (external drive):

[image]

"Mount point" pane in "Disks":

[image]

Comment: Unplug the external storage. Restart your computer. Plug the external storage back in. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, user68186. It stays stuck with this configuration.

Comment: Copy and paste the content of the file `/etc/fstab` in the question. Then format it as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit question window. Then open the app `Disks` and select the external drive in the left panel. Take a screenshot of the Disks Windows and add it to the question as well. There is a picture icon for adding screenshots.

Comment: @user68186 Edited the first post to include the contents of /etc/fstab and a screenshot of the info in "Disks". Also included a screenshot of the "Edit mount options" option after clicking the gear icon under "Volumes" because I though it might be helpful.

Comment: Hello?.........

Comment: If you think the answer below is correct, click on the gray check mark ✔️ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark your problem as solved and help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Background

I think now I understand what happened.

Normally, a new folder is created when an external USB drive is connected to the computer at `/media/your_username/`. When you want to remove an external drive you should use the **Eject** button or unmount the drive before you remove it. At that point this folder is deleted by the system. For whatever reason the two external drives were unsafely disconnected during the upgrade. This left two empty folders in the folder:

```
/media/your_username/
```

These folders are:

```
4TB-WD-ElementsS
8 TB Seagate
```

After the upgrade and possibly after the reboot when the two external drives were recognized again, the system couldn't create those folders as they already existed. So the system added a suffix `1` to the end of those folder names and created new folders.

**Note,** these folders are not "disk-symlinks." They are called "mount points". They are just plain empty folders and can be treated as such once the external drives are "unmounted."

## What to do?

1. First, safely remove the attached USB drives. The easiest way to do this is to click on the **Eject** icon. Wait for the the notification to show that it is safe to remove the drive. Waiting for the "Safe to Remove" message is very important for large drives. Once you see this message unplug the drive. Repeat for the other drive.
2. Delete the offending folders. You will need administrative privileges to do this. Even though it can be done via the File app, it is not straight forward. So I will show you the command-line way:

- Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the commands:

  `sudo rmdir "/media/your_username/4TB-WD-ElementsS/"`

You will be asked to enter your password. When you type the password the cursor will not move and **you will not see** anything line `********`. This is normal. You can delete the other folder similarly

3. Plug back the USB drives and they should now have the correct mount-points.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
Looks like every time you reboot your ubuntu, the system try to recreate a new mount point for every drives in your computer.

I could solve this problem, preventing the system to mount automatically each drives, defining manually where to mount each one.